# Most basic Hash function

Tags: hash

I am trying to understand Hashes better( this question does not have anything to do with particular project).

To be more specific I want to know how can I write a simple hash function that I can user to verify that contents of a file have not changed.

For argument sake can you provide hash function for `python`, `VB`, or `C` to check if csv file has been changed ?

Comment: What about SHA1 or MD5? There should be implementations available for both in all of those languages, or is the goal to write your own?

Comment: This question is extraordinarily broad. Please edit your question to show what you've tried, or narrow it down to a more specific question.